# How to read the full query string in angularjs from url?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use `angularjs` to read the full query string:

http://localhost/test#/?param1=abc&param2=def

I know that `var query = $location.search();` would give my an object containing each param as key-value pair.

But I want to extract the full string `param1=abc&param2=def`, and use this param elsewhere. Without having to know what parameters are inside the string.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular don't have method to get the complete querysting.

You can use [`url()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) to get the URL and then extract the querystring.

```
var queryString = $location.url().split('?')[1];
```